# Spark: How to get partition for each unique value of expression?

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I created tech column that I called `bucket` and use it for repartition my DataFrame. But I get less count of partitions then I have unique values of partitionExpr.

Is there any ways to make Spark to generation exact count of partition?

I do this:

```
val dfPartition = df.repartition(2 * 5, $"loading_dt_part", $"bucket")
```

Where 2 is a count of unique values in loading_dt_part column and 5 is a count of unique values in bucket column.

Then I check my partition:

```
dfPartition
    .select("loading_dt_part", "bucket")
    .distinct()
    .withColumn("partition", spark_partition_id())
    .show(100)
```

and get this:

```
+---------------+------+---------+
|loading_dt_part|bucket|partition|
+---------------+------+---------+
|       20220831|   1.0|        1|
|       20221231|   1.0|        2|
|       20221231|   5.0|        2|
|       20221231|   0.0|        3|
|       20221231|   3.0|        4|
|       20221231|   2.0|        5|
|       20220831|   5.0|        6|
|       20220831|   4.0|        6|
|       20221231|   4.0|        7|
|       20220831|   3.0|        8|
|       20220831|   2.0|        8|
|       20220831|   0.0|        8|
+---------------+------+---------+
```

Here we see, that, for example, bucket 1 and 5 were placed to the same partition. So I get 8 partitions instead of 10 as I want.

I understand why this happen. Because, some hash values can occur in the same bucket after split data into partitions. But maybe is there some way to say Spark to create partition for each hash value that it calculate when does repartition.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use repartitionByRange function:

```
val dfPartition = df
    .repartitionByRange(2 * 5, $"loading_dt_part", $"bucket")
```

But now, I get 9 partition istead of 10, every time.

```
+---------------+------+---------+
|loading_dt_part|bucket|partition|
+---------------+------+---------+
|       20220831|   1.0|        0|
|       20220831|   2.0|        0|
|       20220831|   3.0|        1|
|       20220831|   4.0|        2|
|       20220831|   5.0|        3|
|       20221231|   1.0|        4|
|       20221231|   2.0|        5|
|       20221231|   3.0|        6|
|       20221231|   4.0|        7|
|       20221231|   5.0|        8|
+---------------+------+---------+
```

In this example, value 1 and 2 were placed into 0 partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason why you don't get the desired result using `.repartitionByRange(2 * 5, $"loading_dt_part", $"bucket")` is because `repartitionByRange` uses sampling to estimate the ranges.

In order to make the estimation more accurate, you can increase the sample size using the config `spark.sql.execution.rangeExchange.sampleSizePerPartition` (the default is 100).

Bear in mind that increasing the sample size comes with some performance penalty.